# how facebook is storing and maintain the image in application?

Tags: image, save, store

I'm going to create application where i need to save tons of image and maintain it, so please can any one tell me what is the best practice to save and maintain image, how Facebook does this.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook using Big Data to store images.